Websocket Client not recieving message from server (Handshake OK, Server recieves messages)
My server establishes a connection with the JavaScript client, and upon opening, the server sends a message to the client. However, the client does not receive this message. The client successfully sends messages to the server after the connection opens, and the server receives these and all subsequent messages. Despite this, no messages sent by the server are received by the client.
This setup previously worked without issues on a DigitalOcean server. I have now migrated to my own server located at home, where I have configured port forwarding for managing POST requests and serving content through Nginx. However, I have been unable to determine why the WebSocket communication is not functioning as expected.
I consistently receive a message indicating “received 1001 (going away) then sent 1001 (going away),” which corresponds to an exception on close. This occurs when the page is left or refreshed. While the client correctly displays the opening and closing of the connection, it does not receive any messages from the server.
SERVER CODE:
async def handler(websocket, path) :
    current = None
    print("handling something")
    try :
        async for message in websocket :
            parsedClientMessage = json.loads(message)
            print(parsedClientMessage)
            if parsedClientMessage["type"] == "01" :
                parsedClientData = (parsedClientMessage['message'])
                current = parsedClientData['username'] if type(parsedClientData) is dict and parsedClientData['username'] in Read(storage) else id(websocket)
                if not current in clients :
                    clients[current] = {}
                clients[current][id(websocket)] = websocket
        await websocket.send(["connect", "Welcome to TerminalSaturn!", id(websocket)])

    except Exception as e :
        print(e)
    finally: 
        print(f"closed connection")
        if current in clients :
            if len(clients[current]) - 1 == 0 :
                del clients[current] 
            else :
                del clients[current][id(websocket)] 



async def main() : 
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=cert_path, keyfile=key_path)
    async with websockets.serve(ws_handler=handler, host='0.0.0.0',port=1111, ssl=ssl_context):
        print("WebSocket server is running with SSL/TLS")
        await asyncio.Future() 

CLIENT CODE:
const wsUrl = 'wss://REDACTED:1111';
const socket = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
export var SID = null


socket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log(event)
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: '01', message: utils.getUserData() }));
};

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
    console.log("got msgs")
    console.log(event.data)
    const operations = {
        "rload": () => {
            utils.generateNotification("Admin", "Your data was updated and your page will be automatically refreshed in 3 seconds.")
            setTimeout(() => {
                location.reload()
            }, 1000 * 3);
        },
        "connect": () => {
            console.log("connected")
            utils.generateNotification("Server", data[1])
            SID = data[2]
        },
        "dcl": () => {
            if (utils.getUserData()) {
                utils.logOut()
            }
        }
    }
    if (data[0] in operations) {
        operations[data[0]]()
    }
    else {
        utils.generateNotification("Server", data)
    }
};

I have verified that my certificate is functioning correctly, as I am using WSS, and POST requests with CORS are working without any issues on this certificate. I have also confirmed that there are no antivirus programs, firewalls, or other security measures interfering with the connection. Despite extensive research and troubleshooting efforts, I have been unable to resolve this issue. The only error code I encounter is 1001.

The await websocket.send(["connect", "Welcome to TerminalSaturn!", id(websocket)]) line is located inside the async for message in websocket: loop, which means that the server sends this message only after receiving a message from the client. If the client never sends a message, the server never sends one. To ensure the server sends a welcome message upon opening the connection, move this code outside of the loop, like this:
async def handler(websocket, path):
    current = None
    print("handling something")
    try:
        # Send a welcome message as soon as the connection opens
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(["connect", "Welcome to TerminalSaturn!", id(websocket)]))
        
        async for message in websocket:
            parsedClientMessage = json.loads(message)
            print(parsedClientMessage)
            if parsedClientMessage["type"] == "01":
                parsedClientData = (parsedClientMessage['message'])
                current = parsedClientData['username'] if type(parsedClientData) is dict and parsedClientData['username'] in Read(storage) else id(websocket)
                if not current in clients:
                    clients[current] = {}
                clients[current][id(websocket)] = websocket

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print(f"closed connection")
        if current in clients:
            if len(clients[current]) - 1 == 0:
                del clients[current]
            else:
                del clients[current][id(websocket)]


After extensive troubleshooting, I discovered that while reordering the awaited send was correct, it did not resolve the issue. The underlying problem was due to having a redundant SSL certificate on the WebSocket, in addition to the one on the Nginx server forwarding to my WSS port. Once I removed the certificate from the WebSocket—since Nginx was already handling SSL termination—the issue was resolved. Initially, Nginx was not part of the setup, but I implemented it after migrating to a different device.
